# PHP proc_open avability

Tags: php, proc-open

I made a PHP library that uses `proc_open` and relies on external application to process data.

Now, I need to make a "check" file that will analyze the server and return if my library can be used on it.

I figured these steps are enough:

- Check if proc_open is allowed
- Check if external application is installed

How do I check if proc_open is allowed? Also, I guess proc_open works on windows-based servers too (just using windows command prompt instead of terminal)?

Comment: maybe you need to check if the external application is_executable() by the php user.

Comment: you're right, that needs to be checked too.

Answer (score 2):

`if( function_exists("proc_open"))` would be a good start. Then use a `try..catch` block to attempt to call a simple `proc_open` test. If the test passes, then `proc_open` is allowed.

As for the external application, if it defines any functions you can use `function_exists` to check and see if it is installed and working.

Comment: Oh, I thought function_exist would return true always since proc_open is core PHP function. Will it return false if server admin disabled it?

About using `function_exists` for external app check, how do you mean I can use it through `proc_open`? I wanted to handle this by using `type MY_EXTERNAL_APP` on linux (which allows me to check if external app is installed) and some similar function on windows, I would google it, there must be one.

Comment: @user2742648 not always actually. From server to server, you may encounter a situation where this function simply does not exist.